# How to check if workbook not corrupted

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

My problem is, how to check, if a workbook that is downloaded from sharepoint is not corrupted and can be open. Well, the simplest possible way is to try to open it. I have written a function for that:

```
Function CanBeOpen(sPath As String) As Boolean
Dim wb As Workbook
On Error Resume Next

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wb = .Workbooks.Open(sPath, False, True)
    .SendKeys "~", True 'To close progressbar when opening

    Select Case TypeName(wb)
        Case Is = "Nothing"
            CanBeOpen = False
        Case Is = "Workbook"
            CanBeOpen = True
        Case Else
            CanBeOpen = False
    End Select

    wb.Close savechanges:=False
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

Set wb = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

This is not very efficient approach however. If the file is big, opening it takes significant amount of time. I wonder if somebody know faster and more elegant solution.

Comment: If the code is already working, I would post it over at: [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for more help.

Comment: It is working but I have strong feeling that this is not right direction. In other words, I looking for suggestion how should it be done.

Comment: it seems like [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the right place for your question. They can probably find a better solution for your problem. Read this to know where to post your question [Where To Post Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)